# Install mahout in windows 7 under cygwin

Tags: windows-7, hadoop, cygwin, mapreduce, mahout

I have successfully installed hadoop under cygwin in Windows 7 pro 64 bit.

Now I'm working on installing mahout and I can't.

After setting the MAHOUT_HOME and variable and running mahout on cygwin I get the following error

I guess it has to do with the compatibility issues between cygwin and windows paths but I can't find which specific path should I change.

```
Running on hadoop, using /cygdrive/c/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /cygdrive/c/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /cygdrive               /c/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \cygdrive\c\mahout\mahout
examples-0.7               
-job.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the /cygdrive/c/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar should be C:\mahout\mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar.

```
     MAHOUT_JOB=`cygpath -wp $MAHOUT_JOB
```

Java is a Windows program, and as such, doesn't recognize Cygwin-specific paths. So /cygdrive/c/foo/... is useless to java.exe. If your Java software uses file paths, you'll need to convert them to Windows-style path names using the cygpath tool included with Cygwin.

cygpath takes a UNIX-style path as an argument and returns a Windows-style path. Here's an example:

```
    $ cygpath -wp /cygdrive/c:/cygdrive/c/classes
    c:\;c:\classes
```

So, when calling Java programs (say, from within shell scripts), you'd need to write your command-line like this:

```
java -classpath `cygpath -wp $CLASSPATH` [arguments]
```

Reference: http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/faq/